# What is the difference between these two ways of writing the IF loop?

Tags: python, if-statement

In my tutorial book, the writer formate this program as shown in code no.2. while my intuitive tells me to write the program like shown in code no.1. Both programs get the job done for me, but is there a difference between these two codes? If there is, which way is better, in your opinion?

```
#1
total = 0
count = 0
while (True):
    inp = input('Enter a number: ')
    if inp == 'done':
        break
    else:
        value = float(inp)
        total = total + value
        count = count + 1
average = total / count
print('Average:', average)

#end of 1

#2
total = 0
count = 0
while (True):
    inp = input('Enter a number: ')
    if inp == 'done': break
    value = float(inp)
    total = total + value
    count = count + 1
average = total / count
print('Average:', average)

#end of 2
```

Comment: [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#other-recommendations) discourages one-line if statements

Comment: @khelwood. Thanks! I also think the first version is far more readable, more clear-cut. Good to know!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't any difference in how the code runs, sometimes it might be nicer to use a one line if statement. One way isn't objectively better, it comes down to context and personal preference. So choose the way you prefer. If you are ever in any doubt about Python Syntax and its style check out the official [Python Style Guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

One of the key takes from the style guide is that readability counts, so try to pick the most readable option.

Answer (score 0):

I think your way is more readable, but the extra tab on the if statement as well as the else statement is not necessary. I prefere the first option because of the readability

Answer (score 0):

If you are more comfortable using the first syntax, then you can use it without any problem.

However, let me explain the differences between the two code:
Using 'break' means that whenever `inp == 'done'` is true, then you will exit the current loop and continue. Hence, using an 'else' is not mandatory, because it either reaches or do not reach what you wrote in your 'else' statement, it cannot go in both the if and the else statement.

Otherwise, that is pretty much it, both codes will give you the same thing :D!

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the logic behind this, it was hard for me figuring out the exact functionings of the second code when first saw this. Your answer just makes it a lot more clearer!